# Retrieve each product data from firebase cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have uploaded two product details to cloud firestore as given below

[image]

I have used a way to upload each product and show it in a grid tile..

This is the method I have used to retrieve the data from cloud firestore and when i print the lenght of document is succesfully showing '2'.

```
void getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kollamProducts').get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      category = document['category'];
      id = document['id'];
      name = document['name'];
      shop = document['shop'];
      quantity = document['quantity'];
      images = List.from(document['images']);
      sizes = List.from(document['sizes']);
    });

    if (snapshot.docs.length != 0) {
      setState(() {
        prodL = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
  }
```

This is the grid tile widget I have created. In this it use another widget called Single Product as its itemBuilder.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: false,
      primary: false,
      itemCount: prodL,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SingleProdc(
          product_name: name,
          product_picture: images[0],
          product_image1: images[1],
          product_image2: images[2],
          product_shop: shop,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And the single rpoduct widget arranges everything in a card and shows the product in the grid tile.

```
class SingleProdc extends StatelessWidget {
  final product_name;
  final product_picture;
  final product_image1;
  final product_image2;
  final product_shop;

  SingleProdc(
      {this.product_name,
      this.product_picture,
      this.product_image1,
      this.product_image2,
      this.product_shop});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
        tag: product_name,
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
          child: InkWell(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ProductDetails(
                      product_detail_name: product_name,
                      product_detail_picture: product_picture,
                      product_detail_image1: product_image1,
                      product_detail_image2: product_image2,
                      product_detail_shop: product_shop,
                    ))),
            child: GridTile(
              header: Container(
                height: 30,
                color: Colors.black38,
                child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      product_shop,
                      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
              ),
              footer: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  color: Colors.black38,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        product_name,
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize:
                              product_name.toString().length > 9 ? 10 : 15,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "\u{20B9} 500",
                        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              child: Image.network(
                product_picture,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Problem is when product is displayes instead of showing the two different products, the first one is being duplicated.. Thats not what I want.. The snapshot.docs.length says that there are 2 products..Then why the first one is being replicated..Please help me out.

Comment: I'm new to this, but I don't see where the values of category,id,shop,quantity are being kept. Won't only the latest values be available? They are overwritten foreach document read. You'd want to return a List<Product> from getData and use that list for the builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the error is here:

```dart
void getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kollamProducts').get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
      category = document['category'];
      id = document['id'];
      name = document['name'];
      shop = document['shop'];
      quantity = document['quantity'];
      images = List.from(document['images']);
      sizes = List.from(document['sizes']);
    });

    if (snapshot.docs.length != 0) {
      setState(() {
        prodL = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
  }
```

What you're doing is you're assigning values to some fixed variable. What you should do is return a list:

```dart
Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
  List<dynamic> temp = List();
    QuerySnapshot snapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('kollamProducts').get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((document) {
    temp.add(
    {
      category = document['category'];
      id = document['id'];
      name = document['name'];
      shop = document['shop'];
      quantity = document['quantity'];
      images = List.from(document['images']);
      sizes = List.from(document['sizes']);
    }
  );
});

    if (snapshot.docs.length != 0) {
      setState(() {
        prodL = snapshot.docs.length;
      });
    }
    return temp;
  }
```

Now, you can use the items in the list to access the data and show the Widgets.

Comment: Thanks bro..It worked..Now I get the concept...Thanks a lot bro..

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `getData` is returning `void` instead of `Future<void>`. Try changing that and also, wherever you're calling `getData()`, use `await getData()`.

Edit:
What I'm trying to say is this. Remove the `await getData()` from `initState` and do this.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: getData(),
    builder:(context, snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
        return GridView.builder(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: false,
        primary: false,
        itemCount: prodL,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return SingleProdc(
            product_name: name,
            product_picture: images[0],
            product_image1: images[1],
            product_image2: images[2],
            product_shop: shop,
          );
        },
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: I changed to Future<void> and the function was called in initState. when I add the await it shows error

like this
_ProductKollamListState.initState() returned a Future.

State.initState() must be a void method without an `async` keyword.

Comment: Wait, why are you calling this in initState? Nvm, maybe try using `FutureBuilder` on top of `GirdView`?

Comment: And remove the `getData()` from initState and put in the `future` for `FutureBuilder`

Comment: can u re arrange my code..i didnt undertsnad